# TensorFlow - reproducing results when using dropout

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deterministic, regularized, reproducible-research

I am training a neural network using dropout regularization. I save the weights and biases the network is initialized with, so that I can repeat the experiment when I get good results.

However, the use of dropout introduces some randomness in the network: since dropout drops units randomly, each time I rerun the network, different units are being dropped - even though I initialize the network with the exact same weights and biases (if I understand this correctly).

Is there a way to make the dropout deterministic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two primary ways to perform dropout in tensorflow:

- [`tf.nn.dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) (low-level)
- [`tf.layers.dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout) (high-level, uses `tf.nn.dropout` under the hood)

Both functions accept a `seed` parameter that is used to generate the random mask. By default, `seed=None`, which means random seed, i.e. non-deterministic. In order to make the result deterministic, you either set the seed on per-op level or call [`tf.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) (sets the the graph-level random seed) or, better, both.

Example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.set_random_seed(0)

x = tf.ones([10])
y = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob=0.5, seed=0)
for i in range(5):
  print(y.eval())

z = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=x, rate=0.5, training=True, seed=0)
for i in range(5):
  print(z.eval())
```

Caveat: in general, there are other sources in randomness in the training scripts, so you have to set also pure python seed ([`random.seed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed)) and numpy seed ([`numpy.random.seed`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)).

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm! I hoped it would be this simple.

Comment: Setting both graph seed and  dropout seedd won't force the same inputs always to be dropped out at each iteration?

Comment: @Xema did you ever find the answer? Does seeding the dropout layer ensure that the same masks will be randomly sampled? Maxim, would you know?

Comment: Didn't even remember the question! I moved to pytorch at that time, and never looked back.