# Why do I have different results for the same model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reproducible-research

I use Skopt to find the best hyper-parameters for my model. I fix all the seed with the following code:

```py
import random
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import set_session
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import clear_session
from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend import get_session
from numpy.random import seed

# Reset Keras Session
def reset_keras():
    sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
    tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.clear_session()
    sess.close()
    sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()

    try:
        del classifier # this is from global space - change this as you need
    except:
        pass

    # use the same config as you used to create the session
    config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
    config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 1
    config.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
    tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config))
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = '2'
    os.environ['TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS'] = '1'

    seed(2)
    tf.random.set_seed(2)
    random.seed(2)
```

I use this function before using my model, to clean and restart the seed.

I also fix the seed for each initializer in my model.

```py
def create_model(num_input_nodes,drop_LSTM1,num_LSTM_layers,num_LSTM_nodes,drop_LSTM2,
                     num_input_dense,drop_Dense1,num_dense_layers,num_HLD_nodes,
                     drop_Dense2,optim,activation,loss):

        #start the model making process and create our first layer
            

    
        
        
        model = tf.keras.Sequential()
       #create a loop making a new LSTTM layer for the amount passed to this model.
        #naming the layers helps avoid tensorflow error deep in the stack trace.
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=embedding_dim, 
                                            input_length=sequence_length,
                                            embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Constant(embedding_matrix),
                                            trainable=True))
        if num_LSTM_layers>0:
            
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(num_input_nodes,
                                           dropout=drop_LSTM1,
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2),
    recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Orthogonal(seed=2),
                                           return_sequences=True))
            i=0
    
            while i<num_LSTM_layers-1:
    
                model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(num_LSTM_nodes, return_sequences=True,
                                               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2),
    recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Orthogonal(seed=2), dropout=drop_LSTM2))
                i+=1

            model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(num_LSTM_nodes, dropout=drop_LSTM2,kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2),
    recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Orthogonal(seed=2), return_sequences=False))
        else : 
            model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(num_input_nodes, dropout=drop_LSTM1,kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2),
    recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Orthogonal(seed=2), return_sequences=False))

        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_input_dense,
                         activation=activation,
                                       kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2)))
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop_Dense1,seed=2))
        if num_dense_layers>0:
            for i in range(num_dense_layers):
                
                model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_HLD_nodes,
                         activation=activation,
                                               kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2)))
                model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop_Dense2,seed=2))
        #add our classification layer.
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax',
                                        kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=2)))

        #setup our optimizer and compile

        model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss=loss,
                     metrics=[      tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
          tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),F1Score(num_classes=2,name='F1',average='macro')])
        print(model.summary())
        return model
```

Moreover, my Embedding Layer is initialized with a custom Embedding Matrix.
But I already see a difference.
Do I need to fix another seed ?

**EDIT**

Seems I forgot to fix `shuffle=False`in the `fit` method.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to find out exactly what you need to fix in this code, but check if you already fixed data split, dropout, or init values in your model.

Comment: it's exactly the same train/test data. I also fix all the dropout and init values, except LSTM dropout but it's impossible to fix it...

Comment: this should be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175704/tensorflow-reproducing-results-when-using-dropout

Comment: I already fix the TF seed's in my function `reset_keras`